# Is it possible to abstract the singleton pattern from the class itself?

Tags: typescript, class, oop, design-patterns, singleton

Working with `typescript`/`javascript` I have built a collection of singletons.

However, in an attempt to refactor and abstract the implementation, I tried to prepare a class which will implement that singleton logic and for them to extend. This was apparently naive of me, since the situation leads to constructor problems and seems to be unfeasible.

So my question, is it possible to elegantly apply singleton behavior on a collection of classes / objects?

In the following code, just out of readability it would be nice to abstract away the singleton logic. Further, specifically, I would like to coerce other classes in this collection, as they are added by contributors, to implement them as singletons. It would be a little nicer to do that by just "pluggin in" some abstracted extended class or some sort of wrapper.

```js
class Car {
  /* Singleton Implementation Start */
  private static _instance: Car;

  private constructor() {}

  public static getInstance(): Car {
    if (!Car._instance) {
      Car._instance = new Car();
    }
    return Car._instance;
  }
  /* Singleton Implementation End */

  private _name = "Audi"
  private _color = 'red';
  private _maxSpeed = 150;

  drive(){
    console.log(`WOW! You are riding your cool ${this._color} ${this._name} at ${150} kmh!` )
  }

  paint(color: string){
    this._color = color;
  }
}

class Plane {
  /* Singleton Implementation Start */
  private static _instance: Plane;

  private constructor() {}

  public static getInstance(): Plane {
    if (!Plane._instance) {
      Plane._instance = new Plane();
    }
    return Plane._instance;
  }
  /* Singleton Implementation End */

  private _motors = 4;
  private _maxSpeed = 550;

  fly(){
    console.log(`WOW! You are flying your plane with roaring ${_motors} motors at ${150} kmh!` )
  }
}
```

Comment: Extend a class maybe? https://tsplay.dev/wRXvYm

Comment: I'd recommend against. Rather, have a factory that just controls the lifetime. Factory is much more general, singleton can be seen as an example of a facade over the factory. On the other hand, a factory can do whatever you want, create proxies, singletons, control some business rules.

Comment: @WiktorZychla could you refer me to something that can elaborate on this

Comment: @caTS interesting, I didn't think of creating a class returning function. Does this pattern have a name you are aware of? Looks very nice.

Comment: @caTS it deserves to be posted  as answer I guess.

Answer (score 5):

If we create a factory function that takes a generic:

```
function Singleton<T>() {
    return class Singleton {
        static instance: T; // must be public

        protected constructor() {}

        public static getInstance(): T {
            if (!this.instance) this.instance = new this() as T;

            return this.instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Then we can extend the class returned and provide the generic as the class itself:

```
class Car extends Singleton<Car>() {
  private _name = "Audi"
  private _color = 'red';
  private _maxSpeed = 150;

  drive(){
    console.log(`WOW! You are riding your cool ${this._color} ${this._name} at ${150} kmh!` )
  }

  paint(color: string){
    this._color = color;
  }
}
```

This has to be done with a function since static members cannot reference type parameters of the class. Also, a downside is that you can't have any private or protected members.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NVbzMN)

Comment: Trying to access `Car.getInstance()` raises a runtime exception, `Cannot read private member from an object whose class did not declare it`. You could possibly comment/fix that.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Aw man, now we have to use a public property - I really wish there were protected fields in JS, too.

Comment: Yeah, I wish that too. Upvoted anyways.

Comment: I have unmarked this as correct answer, since it is still possible to construct multiple different instances of Plane or Car with different properties.

checkout code: shorturl.at/amLOY

Comment: @aviya.developer: not sure where your last comment should lead to, but for me this tries to redirect to instagram (rather than to a fiddle with an example). For anyone, like myself, without an instagram account, this effectively means the comment is out of the discussion. Could you possibly fix that?

Comment: @WiktorZychla Oh my no no that was just an attempt to shorten an extremely long typescript playground link!! I will try to fix this...